# Filter for one or more elements in an array

Tags: powershell

Basically I want to do this in PowerShell.

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase "OU=myOU,DC=domain,DC=biz" -Filter {name -eq "_Computer" -or name -eq "_Devices"}
```

But, I want to declare the Strings in an array because I need them more often.

Easily said, I want to do this. But, of course, it does not work!

```
$Strings = @("_Computer", "_Devices")

Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase "OU=myOU,DC=domain,DC=biz" -Filter {name -eq $Strings}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***most convenient* solution** is to use a retrieve-all `-Filter` argument (`-Filter *`) and then pipe to the `Where-Object` cmdlet, which enables use of the `-in` operator, which tests array containment (PSv3+):

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase "OU=myOU,DC=domain,DC=biz" -Filter * |
  Where-Object name -in $Strings
```

Use of a separate `Where-Object` call is needed, because the AD cmdlets' `-Filter` parameter does not support the `-in` operator - it is important to understand that it is the target cmdlet, not PowerShell, that interprets the `-Filter` argument.

Note, however, that **this convenience has *serious performance implications***: use of a `-Filter` argument is typically much faster and more efficient than combining unfiltered retrieval with later filtering *in PowerShell*, because `-Filter` filters *at the source* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42033346/45375) for a `-Filter`-based solution and background information.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

- The `-Filter` parameter of AD cmdlets doesn't support the `-in` (array containment) operator, so `-Filter { name -in $Strings }` is *not* an option - see [about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527(v=ws.10).aspx).
- While using a pipeline with `Where-Object` *is* an option, as in [Martin Brandl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41981645/45375) - to let *PowerShell* do the filtering *later*, after unfiltered retrieval - it will be much slower and less efficient than using `-Filter`.
- To use `-Filter`, emulate `-in` by synthesizing the filter as a *string* (which, in fact, it *is*) from an array of `-eq` expressions joined with `-or`:

```
# Sample organizational unit names.
$Strings = @("_Computer", "_Devices")

# Construct the filter string; with the sample input, this yields a single
# string with the following content:
#     Name -eq "_Computer" -or Name -eq "_Devices"
$Filter = ($Strings | ForEach-Object { "Name -eq `"$_`"" }) -join ' -or '

#`# Pass the filter string to the AD cmdlet.
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase "OU=myOU,DC=domain,DC=biz" -Filter $Filter
```

---

#### Background information:

- **`-Filter` arguments are interpreted by the *target cmdlet*, not *PowerShell***.
- **The syntax of filters is prescribed by the target cmdlet**, and that syntax may or may not be PowerShell-*like* and can vary from cmdlet to cmdlet (group).

  - You must **consult the target cmdlet's documentation to learn what syntax to use** - **do not assume that you can pass arbitrary script blocks containing PowerShell expressions**; for instance:

    - AD cmdlets such as `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` support a very limited, domain-specific expression language that uses PowerShell-*like* syntax, but with many quirks and exceptions - see [about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527(v=ws.10).aspx).
    - By contrast, the FileSystem provider-related cmdlets such as `Get-ChildItem` support only a single wildcard expression as a `-Filter` argument, such as `*.txt`, and the specific wildcard-expression dialect is distinct from PowerShell's own and even *platform-dependent* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059214/45375) of mine.
- Despite their limitations and lack of direct PowerShell integration, **filters have an important advantage: they filter objects *at the source*, which makes for much faster and more efficient retrieval** compared to *unfiltered* retrieval piped to the PowerShell's `Where-Object` cmdlet for *later* filtering.
- **Filters are technically *strings* (`[string]` instances).**

  - It is better to **construct and pass them *as strings*, not PowerShell *script blocks*.**
  - While **passing a script block** may seem convenient, especially to simplify quoting, it has **pitfalls**, because the script block is invariably converted to a `[string]`:

    - The string representation of a script block is simply the string between the opening `{` and the closing `}`, as-is, including whitespace. For instance, this means that script block `{ name -eq $var }` turns into a string whose *literal* content is  `name -eq $var`  - in other words: `$var` is *not interpolated*.
    - While *the AD cmdlets then do seem to apply an extra round of string interpolation*<sup>[1]</sup>
      to the resulting literal - which is not true of `Get-ChildItem`, for instance - even that has pitfalls:

      - Script blocks such as `{ name -eq $someObj.Name }` will *not* work, because accessing *properties* of variables does *not* work directly in an interpolated string (use of `$(...)`, the subexpression operator is required - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) of mine for background).
      - With *implicit remoting*, this extra round of string interpolation may happen *remotely*, where *local* variables are not accessible.
    - It  may give the false impression that regular PowerShell expressions are supported.

---

<sup>[1] This is what I infer from the observed behavior. Do tell us if you know more / know this inference to be incorrect.</sup>