# Batch renaming in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-processing

I'm trying to update a bunch of .jpg images so that they refresh on my website. They're currently stored on my PC like this:

```
media
+- random-project
|  +- 1.jpg
|  +- 2.jpg
|  +- 3.jpg
|  `- thumb.png
+- another-random-project
|  +- 1.jpg
|  `- thumb.png
```

I'm trying to batch rename all `1.jpg, 2.jpg` etc. to `1a.jpg, 2a.jpg`.

I'm thinking using Windows PowerShell and something like

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "[0-9]+.jpg" | foreach { $_.FullName}

Dir *.jpg | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name  -replace "[0-9]+.jpg","[0-9]a.jpg" }
```

but have never used the program before. What do you think?

Comment: you can use the `-whatif` switch to check what is about to happen without doing anything. `Rename-Item` supports that

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go :)

Comment: `-replace "[0-9]+.jpg","[0-9]a.jpg"` -> `-replace '([0-9]+).jpg','$1a.jpg'`

Answer (score 1):

- **It's always worth using the `-Filter` parameter**, if available: it performs filtering *at the source* and is therefore typically much faster than filtering *later*.
- **The *syntax* of the (string) value accepted by the `-Filter` parameter is *cmdlet*- / *PowerShell drive provider-specific*.**
  In the case of **`Get-ChildItem`** (and its built-in aliases `dir` and, in *Windows* PowerShell, `ls`), it accepts a **single wildcard expression** - *similar* to, but distinct from PowerShell's own [wildcard expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) - whose **supported syntax is platform-dependent**:

  - On *Windows*, the expression may only contain `*` and `?` wildcards - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739503/45375).
  - In PowerShell Core on *Unix* platforms, the expression may also contain character sets such as `[0-9]`.

**`[0-9]+.jpg` does *not* work as a `-Filter` value, because it is a *regex* (regular expression)**.

<sup>As an aside: You probably meant to use `.` as a *literal*, in which case you'd have to *escape* it in the regex as `\.`, because `.` is a regex *metacharacter* representing *any* char. in the input.</sup>

You cannot emulate regular expression `[0-9]+.jpg` with a wildcard expression, because even when **wildcard expressions** do support character sets such as `[0-9]`, they **lack subexpression duplication symbols (quantifiers) such as `+`** and `*` and `?`.
(By contrast, *wildcard* metacharacters `*` / `?` are *stand-alone* constructs that represent *any possibly empty sequence of characters* / *exactly one character*).

---

<sup>Note: `-WhatIf` has been added to the `Rename-Item` calls below to *preview* any changes that *would* be made.

Remove `-WhatIf` to perform actual renaming.</sup>

**[*PowerShell Core on Unix only*]** ***If* all `*.jpg` files of interest have a base name (filename root) that is limited to a *single-digit* number**, (e.g., `1.jpg`, ..., `9.jpg`), you can get away with passing *wildcard expression* `[0-9].jpg` to `-Filter`:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter [0-9].jpg |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + 'a' + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

Note how passing script-block argument `{ $_.BaseName + 'a' + $_.Extension }` to parameter `-NewName` constructs the new filename from the input file's base name, followed by literal `a`, followed by the input file's extension.

---

***Otherwise*,**

- **use *wildcard* expression `*.jpg` for efficient *pre*-filtering**,
- then **narrow the pre-filtered results down to specific *regex*-based matches with a `Where-Object` call** that uses `-match` to compare each input file's base name to *regex* `^[0-9]+$`, i.e., to test if it is only composed of decimal digits.

<sup>Note:

* The command below uses PSv3+ `Get-ChildItem` and `Where-Object` syntax.

* The regex passed to `-match` uses *single*-quoting (`'...'`) rather than double-quoting (`"..."`) to ensure that PowerShell's string interpolation doesn't get in the way.</sup>

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.jpg |
  Where-Object BaseName -match '^[0-9]+$' |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + 'a' + $_.Extension  } -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

`Gci` and `Dir` or `ls` are all aliases to `Get-ChildItem`.
They only use wildcards in the filter option not regular expressions.
To include only basenames consisting only of numbers you could:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.jpg" |
  Where-Object BaseName -match "^[0-9]+$"|
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name  -replace '([0-9]+)\.jpg','$1a.jpg'} -whatif
```

If the output seems ok, remove the `-whatif in the last line.`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -recurse -file -Filter "*.jpg" | 
    where Basename -match "^\d$" | 
        Rename-Item -NewName {$("{0}{1}" -f $_.basename, "a.jpg")}
```